# Creating AST for binary expressions

Tags: python, parsing, context-free-grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, ply

I inherited an ANTLR grammar and now implement it without any change with Python Lex Yacc. My Problem is, that ANTLR normally uses very high level EBNF to define a grammar, whereas Yacc uses simple context free grammar.

I struggle with the AST definition of binary expressions. Given from ANTLR, they look like

```
disjunction
: conjunction ('||' conjunction)*
```

This definition exists for precedence reasons, do not wonder about the names.

In my CFG, it looks like

```
def p_sum(self, p):
""" sum : product product_list """
???

def p_product_list(self, p):
""" product_list : PLUS product product_list
| MINUS product product_list
| epsilon
"""
???
```

Some other expressions look like

```
def p_disjunction_1(self, p):
""" disjunction : conjunction """
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_disjunction_2(self, p):
""" disjunction : conjunction OR disjunction """
    p[0] = BinaryOp(p[2], p[1], p[3], p[1].coord)
```

What I want is that my AST consists only of BinaryExpression Nodes, as given in the second example:

BinaryExpression('+', lhs, rhs)

But this grammar gives me a list of factors. Is there any way I can write it in my way? The ??? are the places where I need to but an expression to build my AST, but I cannot think of a nice way to do it. What I see is to define a node with a list of unary expressions, but that is ugly for me. Or is there another way to write the grammar? I do not dare to touch it, since I fear I will alter it in a way which parses different stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "original" form of the `disjunction` production (before it had left-recursion eliminated to make it appropriate for LL parsing) was

```
disjunction: conjunction
           | disjunction '|' conjunction
           ;
```

That will left-associate disjunction; if you want right-association -- for example for assignment operators -- use right-recursion:

```
assignment: expression
          | expression '=' assignment
          ;
```

(That might not be precisely what you want on the left-hand side of an assignment operator, but it shows a general pattern for right-associative rules.)

Similarly:

```
sum: product
   | sum '+' product
   | sum '-' product
   ;
```

The reconstruction of the grammar corresponding to a sensible parse tree should be fairly mechanical, but you probably should write enough test cases, parsing them with both grammars, to assure yourself that you got it correct.

Comment: How do you know what the original form of the disjunction production was? Is it really that easy to replace the Kleene star of the ANTLR EBNF?

Comment: @reindeer: strictly speaking, I don't know for sure, because it might have been left- or right- associative. But disjunction is almost always left-associative so I confidently asserted that. However, I provided both translations, just in case :)

Comment: @reindeer: Also, you an always replace `nt: A B*` with `nt: A | nt B`. That will generate the same language. So in some sense, yes, it is really that easy.